# Automake under linux, executable missing the .out extension.

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

I'm using autotools (autoconfig and automake) under Linux, but my executables are missing the .out extension. What am I forgetting to do?

Comment: There are no filename extension requirements - for example, you don't use `less.out`, `more.out` or `ls.out`, or `autoconf.out` for that matter. You might be confusing the issue with [a.out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out) as a default output (and binary format).

Comment: @BrettHale: Make your comment an answer.